# Check Permutation of string in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

The Question I have is :
For a given two strings, 'str1' and 'str2', check whether they are a permutation of each other or not.
Permutations of each other
Two strings are said to be a permutation of each other when either of the string's characters can be rearranged so that it becomes identical to the other one.

Example:
str1= "sinrtg"
str2 = "string"

The character of the first string(str1) can be rearranged to form str2 and hence we can say that the given strings are a permutation of each other.
Input Format:
The first line of input contains a string without any leading and trailing spaces, representing the first string 'str1'.

The second line of input contains a string without any leading and trailing spaces, representing the second string 'str2'.
Note:
All the characters in the input strings would be in lower case.
Output Format:
The only line of output prints either 'true' or 'false', denoting whether the two strings are a permutation of each other or not.

You are not required to print anything. It has already been taken care of. Just implement the function.

My code for this:

```
public static boolean isPermutation(String str1, String str2) {
    //Your code goes here
    boolean ans=false;
    
    if (str1.length()==str2.length()){
        for (int i=0;i<str1.length();i++){
               ans=false;
            for (int j=0;j<str2.length();j++){
                if (str1.charAt(i)==str2.charAt(j)){
                    ans=true;}
            }
            if (ans == false){
            break;}
    }   
}else{
        return false;
    }
  return ans;
}
```

One test case is giving me a wrong answer . Cany anybody help which test case will this code not work for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code checks two things:

- That `str1` and `str2` have the same length.
- For each character in `str1`, that this character exists in `str2`.

This does not work, as you found out.

A trivial example is:

- `str1` = `"hello"`
- `str2` = `"ehhlo"`

Note how these are *not* permutations: `str2` has 2 `h` characters and only one `l`. However, they have the same length, and `str2` contains every character in `str1`.

One convoluted solution is to not just scan for the target letter, but also *remove* it (use it up). This would be easier if you pile all characters in a list first.

However, there is a *vastly simpler* way to do all this, and to make the algorithm considerably faster to boot. As this is clearly homework, and not the direct question you asked, I'll simply give you a hint: Is there a thing you can do to both `str1` and `str2` such that, once that's been done, the question can be answered simply by checking if `str1` and `str2` are equal?

Comment: we can strike off characters in both the strings while matching and then  can check the length of both the strings . if they both are same then they are permutation else they are not . Is this the approach you gave the hint about ?

Comment: No. You're still doing stuff to string B depending on what you saw in A. My hint is about: Do something to just A without any idea what B is, then do the exact same thing to B (which requires zero knowledge about what A is). And now `a.equals(b)` is all you need to do.

Comment: Here's the skeleton: `String aPrime = mutate(a); String bPrime = mutate(b); return aPrime.equals(bPrime);` - the challenge is: Figure out what the `mutate` method does.